# How to get each json object from a string in clojure?

Tags: json, clojure

I have a single string like with multiples json:

{"operation": {"status": true, "limit": 100}}{"operation1": {"customer": "Jhon", "sum": 20, "time": "2019-02-13T10:00:00.000Z"}}{"operation1": {"customer": "Henry", "sum": 90, "time": "2019-02-13T11:00:00.000Z"}}

I would like to get a list of json to be able to process each json as an individual object.

Comment: Please add what you have tried and how it failed (e.g. exceptions).  So we can improve on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use json library with streaming support.  E.g.

```clj
(require '[cheshire.core :as json])

(->> "{\"operation\": {\"status\": true, \"limit\": 100}}{\"operation1\": {\"customer\": \"Jhon\", \"sum\": 20, \"time\": \"2019-02-13T10:00:00.000Z\"}}{\"operation1\": {\"customer\": \"Henry\", \"sum\": 90, \"time\": \"2019-02-13T11:00:00.000Z\"}}"
     char-array
     io/reader
     json/parsed-seq
     (take 2))
```

returns

```clj
({"operation" {"status" true, "limit" 100}} 
 {"operation1" {"customer" "Jhon", "sum" 20, "time" "2019-02-13T10:00:00.000Z"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to clean up your data.  You may need to clarify where it is coming from so your question is more understandable (in context).

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [tupelo.string :as ts]))

; NOTE:  I added square-brackets to wrap everyting in an array, and I also
; had to add commas between the array entries
(def data
  "[ {'operation': {'status': true, 'limit': 100}},
     {'operation1': {'customer': 'Jhon', 'sum': 20, 'time': '2019-02-13T10:00:00.000Z'}},
     {'operation1': {'customer': 'Henry', 'sum': 90, 'time': '2019-02-13T11:00:00.000Z'}} ] " )
```

with result

```
(t/json->edn (ts/quotes->double data)) => 
  ({:operation {:status true, :limit 100}}
   {:operation1
     {:customer "Jhon", :sum 20, :time "2019-02-13T10:00:00.000Z"}}
   {:operation1
     {:customer "Henry", :sum 90, :time "2019-02-13T11:00:00.000Z"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

*This does not deserve to count as an answer beyond the helpful one by [@rmcv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092373/233334), but it is too much for just a comment.  If useful, @rmcv should feel free to add this context to their answer and I can then delete this answer...*

If you want to return the JSON keywords as Clojure keywords then a tweak to that answer is:

```clj
;; Emits map with JSON keys as Clojure keywords...
(-> "{\"operation\": {\"status\": true, \"limit\": 100}}{\"operation1\":      {\"customer\": \"Jhon\", \"sum\": 20, \"time\": \"2019-02-13T10:00:00.000Z\"}{\"operation1\": {\"customer\": \"Henry\", \"sum\": 90, \"time\": \"2019-02-13T11:00:00.000Z\"}}"
    char-array
    io/reader
    (json/parsed-seq true)
    (->> (take 2)))
```

which returns

```clj
({:operation {:status true, :limit 100}} 
 {:operation1 {:customer "Jhon", :sum 20, :time "2019-02-13T10:00:00.000Z"}})
```

The `true` argument to `parsed-seq` just applies this function to the JSON keywords

```clj
(fn [k] (keyword k))
```

and you can do more complex things with the keyword processing this way, i.e. (not so complex):

```clj
(-> "{\"operation\": {\"status\": true, \"limit\": 100}}{\"operation1\": {\"customer\": \"Jhon\", \"sum\": 20, \"time\": \"2019-02-13T10:00:00.000Z\"}}{\"operation1\": {\"customer\": \"Henry\", \"sum\": 90, \"time\": \"2019-02-13T11:00:00.000Z\"}}"
    char-array
    io/reader
    (chesire/parsed-seq (fn [k] (keyword (clojure.string/upper-case k))))
    (->> (take 2)))
```

returns

```clj
({:OPERATION {:STATUS true, :LIMIT 100}} 
 {:OPERATION1 {:CUSTOMER "Jhon", :SUM 20, :TIME "2019-02-13T10:00:00.000Z"}})
```